# How to save a whole array in a single element of table?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I'm trying to save an entire array to a single table cell. When I try `array2table` or `cell2table`, the result looks like this (second column):

[image]

Whereas I want it to be like this:

[image]

It means that I want the **car** column items to be this way:

```
[554,996,53,25]
[326,805,37,14]
...
```

What can I do to save each array in a single table cell and avoid separation of the array's elements. 
I've already tried this:

```
formatSpec = '[%f %f %f %f]';
sprintf(formatSpec, x, y, w, h)
```

But the result comes with **quotations** on the sides:

```
'[554,996,53,25]'
'[326,805,37,14]'
```

But I don't want the ''.

Comment: The `car` column *is* that way. The values are a single array in the same table column. `sprintf` returns a string, so it's quite logical that the result has quotation marks.

Comment: @excaza thank you. You are right, the error I got was for another reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming car is the matrix of numbers you are trying to manipulate and is of size numRows by 4 columns, have you tried using `mat2cell` to break each row into its own cell and work from there?

```
 valCell = mat2cell(cars, ones(size(cars,1),1), 4);
 %valCell{1} holds row 1 as one cell
 % the table could be contructed of this cell array 
 % and a cell array of your names  {names, values}
```

Not entirely sure of your end goal but that should get you on your way